# Clients lose connectivity to Router when Streaming Netflix HD

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, interference, wireless-extender

### Devices Setup

**Router 1 - TP-Link Archer C60** (Floor 1)

```
LAN IP: 192.168.1.1
DHCP Range: 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.99
Channel = 11
```

**Router 2 - TP-Link WR-840N** (Floor 2)

This Router is connected LAN to LAN to Router 1 and setup as an Access Point.

```
LAN IP: 192.168.1.2
DHCP = Disabled
Channel = 6
```

This LAN IP on Router 2 is set via TP Link’s Smart IP (DHCP) but I have reserved it for Router 2 within Router 1’s DHCP.

### The Problem

When I stream Netflix HD at my Chromecast connected wirelessly to router 2, other clients lose internet connectivity and ping to router 2 fails for as long as the Chromecast keeps streaming. However, everything is smooth when connected to the same router 2 via LAN.

Chromecast is placed at the far end of the house but I get enough signal power to stream in HD. The problem also goes away when Chromecast is brought closer to the router where signal power is stronger.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107525/discussion-on-question-by-asad-moeen-clients-lose-connectivity-to-router-when-st).

Answer (score 0):

I changed my wifi router to a dual-band device and streamed through 5Ghz, however, the same problem persisted. The 5Ghz was slowed down whereas the 2.4Ghz worked fine. I googled about Chromecast for this issue and found that the device indeed sent a large amount of data to routers.

https://www.techradar.com/news/your-chromecast-might-be-strangling-your-home-wi-fi-network

All my devices are iOS so I believe the problem is not Android specific. The second Chromecast device I have works fine, it’s only this one causing problems.